# left hand/foot rule in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, sql-server-2016, sqlgeography

I have seen that SQL Server uses left hand/foot rule while creating polygons. But the articles I have read are talking about SQL Server 2012 and I am not sure if it's the case with SQL Server 2016 as well. Do we have to start specifying the points in counter clock wise direction for left hand/foot rule to generate polygons.

Comment: It's "fishing education" day here at SO! What happens if you create a simple polygon with the ordering of points clockwise? Counterclockwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, I understand that if we specify points in clockwise direction, it takes all the points in the entire world except the region of the polygon whereas if we specify in counter clockwise direction, we get the expected region.